# Cannot save file to disc / sandbox in iOS -- how to troubleshoot / solve?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I am new to iOS development. Is there a way that I could dig deeper to find out why it is not saving properly? I already use iExplorer to look at the file directory, but it doesn't really help me if the file won't even save.

The full filepath it ends up trying to save to is:

```
"file:///var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/2269079E-82ED-4129-9A59-D3E55C068B7B/Documents//pendingRequests.plist"
```

I can also confirm that the queue (of type `NSMutableArray`) does have items in it.

Here is my code, which seems to always return 0 (false):

```
- (BOOL)saveQueueToDisk
{   
    NSString *fileName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/pendingRequests.plist", [self applicationDocumentsDirectory]];

    BOOL didSave = [NSKeyedArchiver archiveRootObject:_requestQueue toFile:fileName];
    NSLog(@"Saving queue to location: %@", fileName);
    NSLog(@"Queue save status:%hhd", didSave);

    return didSave;
}
```

I also tried it without the double slash near the end in the file path, and it still did not save.

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/icloud/documentation/data-storage/index.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This ended up working for me:

```
- (BOOL)saveQueueToDisk
{
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *filePath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"pendingRequests.plist"];

    BOOL didSave = [NSKeyedArchiver archiveRootObject:_requestQueue toFile:filePath];

    return didSave;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your path is malformed, you've got an empty directory component:

```
file:///var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/2269079E-82ED-4129-9A59-D3E55C068B7B/Documents**//**pendingRequests.plist
```

You can use NSString's native methods to create paths more easily:

```
[[self applicationDocumentsDirectory] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"pendingRequests.plist"]
```

Comment: That line `fileName = [[self applicationDocumentsDirectory] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"pendingRequests.plist"];` actually throws an exception and crashes the app. "unrecognized selector sent to instance"

Comment: @Marcel is `applicationDocumentsDirectory` returning an NSURL? In that case, you'll need to use `[[self applicationDocumentsDirectory] URLByAppendingPathComponent:"and so on"]`

Comment: `applicationDocumentsDirectory` returns a string. All of this code is happening with strings; not URLs

Comment: Weird. It shouldn't be throwing an exception, are you sure there's not an error somewhere else?

Comment: Nope; it's that specific line

Comment: Can you show me what `[applicationDocumentsDirectory]` looks like? If it is an `NSString`, you shouldn't be getting an exception. See: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSString/stringByAppendingPathComponent:

Comment: `- (NSString *)applicationDocumentsDirectory
{
      return  [[[NSFileManager defaultManager] URLsForDirectory:NSDocumentDirectory inDomains:NSUserDomainMask] lastObject];
}`

Comment: `[NSFileManager URLsForDirectory:inDomains]` returns an `NSArray` of `NSURL`s, not `NSString`s. That is why you are getting your error (which I suggested earlier): https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSFileManager_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSFileManager/URLsForDirectory:inDomains: